# How to get value after e for python floats

Tags: python, scientific-notation, ieee

I frequently enter values in scientific notation (e.g. 3.472e-07) for floats in Python. Is there a simple way to access the exponent of a given float in Python?

E.g. given `x = 4.7820012347239297234e-7`, is there some way to just get the value after e (in this case, -7).

Thanks!

Comment: Probably some way using `log`.

Comment: if x is a string you can use .find to get the location of e and then slice the string from e to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Take the log of the number and round the value accordingly.

```
for val in [12345678901234567890.0, .0000004782]:
    logval = math.log10(val)
    print val, logval, round(logval - (0.5 if logval<0 else 0))
```

(2) Convert it to string, grab the first occurrence of "e" [from the right end](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rfind.htm), and take the remainder of the string.

```
for val in [12345678901234567890.0, .0000004782]:
    valstr = "{0:e}".format(val)
    epos = valstr.rfind('e')
    exponent = valstr[epos+1:]
    print int(exponent)
```

Would either of those work for you?

Comment: Brilliant feel like an idiot for not thinking of using log. Also want to highlight use of `math.log10` and not `math.log` unless using base 2

Comment: math.log is base epsilon (2.718281828...), not 2.  Don't goof that up; I've already tried it, and the package refuses to read my mind.  Also, note that you can specify a base to use.

Comment: Probably also take absolutely value first to handle negative number.